# What do debug and packageName fields actually do?

Tags: android, debugging

I was looking through Google documentation about WindowManager.LayoutParams (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) and found there 2 fields : packagename and debug. Can someone explain me how to work with them? Something like this,right?

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.debug("debug");
params.packageName = "some package";
```

Then where should see "debug" string? And this params will be used only when some app with package name "some package" is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then where should see "debug" string?

Anywhere you want, reading API:

```
Stringdebug(String output)
```

> Returns a String representation of **this set of layout parameters**.

Just:

```
                                 // not sure if layoutname is correct value!
System.out.println(params.debug("layoutname"));
```

or

```
                                   // not sure if layoutname is correct value!
Log.d("debugString", params.debug("layoutname"));
```

Will return a String with the following format: `output + "ViewGroup.LayoutParams={ width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT }"`

> And this params will be used only when some app with package name "some package" is running?

Actually no, packagename is an attribute and you dont have permissions to change it.

Comment: Thanks. So, params.packageName is useless?

Comment: if you have just one `Layout` you think in this way, but is useful because gives you info about `LayoutParams` you're managing, and in a big app you can have multiple packages coming